# Using Vue.js inside Django template

Tags: python, django, vue.js, npm

What I would like to accomplish is to set a django block content inside a vue app. I used vue cli to create a vue app but I am not able to do the following.

views.py

```
def login(request):
    template_name = 'login.html'
    return render(request, template_name)
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<body>
<div id="app">
    {% block component %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>

</html>
<script src="{% static 'assets/js/app.js' %}"></script>
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block component %}
    <myComponent />
{%  endblock %}
```

What kind of setup do I need to build app.js in way that I can put whatever component I want in the templates?

below is the NOT working vue files

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false



new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Currently if I add tags within the component block in login.html nothing changes.
If I add a  tag inside App.vue it will show up in login.html but I want to be able to choose which components will be displayed.

EDIT:
I have made some progress and kind of accomplished what I want but not 100%
I copied files over from a laravel project that uses vue in the way I have described.

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

This configuration accomplishes what I want but I do not want to use the laravel-mix. I tried removing it from the package.json and webpack.mix.js and I receive build fails. The laravel-mix is described as a configuration layer on top of webpack so I'm assuming if I can get pointed in the right direction with how to set that up properly, I will be good to go.